# Are there significant resource-usage differences among: HTTP polling VS Websocket VS Webhooks?

Tags: c#, node.js, server, desktop-application

There is the following scenario:

The `desktop app` communicates with `node.js` server to get the updates/messages. For example, 100 users have that `desktop-app` open. Will server get less load if I choose either #1,#2 or #3 method:

1) having http request sending to backend once in every second to get the new message

2) having websocket connection to get the new message

3) having webhook to send message to desktop app

(my goal here is about server resource usage and goal to have less server load. I am not familiar, but answers are also welcomed mentioning http/2 protocol)

Comment: This will likely depend on many more parameters than just the connection type.

Comment: Probably the actual implementation, the libraries being used, etc. I'm not an expert on either of these methods, but I would assume that you won't find out unless you actually test and measure it. And then the next question will be which of the solutions scales better. I could imagine that the http request is is slowest but scales best as it doesn't require keeping (eventually) tens of thousands of connections open.

Comment: @PMF thanks for your thoughts.. that's what i want to know if it really uses less resources of not